# Extracting a rectangle shaped object from an image

Tags: python, image-processing

[Testing image of voltmeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUaXn.jpg)

So I'm fairly new to the area and have been dabbling with images. I've been having some unstable results for lack of better words. I'm essentially trying to detect the voltmeter in variations of the above image and extracting the white region or as close to the white region as possible.

The problem is, it works for some variations of images but not for others. So, my questions are:

- Is there a somewhat quick and efficient method of detecting and extracting the required region? (Quick being somewhat secondary)
- What is the thought process behind a task like this for some of you with actual experience and expertise in the field?

I've tried:

- Checking various color spaces and specific planes in those color spaces for ease of information extraction
- Histogram Equalization, threshold, blurring, edge detection
- Contouring and a couple of odd things in between.

I'm a bit stuck on achieving a "robust" or somewhat "generalized" way of detecting the said area in variations of the above image.

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code:

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
im = cv2.imread("volt.jpg")

imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 150, 200, 0)
#imedge = cv2.Canny(imgray, 30, 200) 


contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) 

plt.imshow(thresh)

voltcnt = 0
x = 0
for i in range(0, len(contours)):
    if cv2.contourArea(contours[i]) > 50000 and cv2.contourArea(contours[i]) < 100000:
        voltcnt = cv2.contourArea(contours[i])
        x = i
        
cv2.drawContours(im, contours[x], -1, (255, 0, 0), 3) 
plt.imshow(im)
```

Here's the output:
[image]

You can also try with "cv2.SimpleBlobDetector()"

Comment: For most general approach you have to use Deep Learning based detection & segmentation.

Comment: Oh wow, guess I was using contouring wrong. Thanks for the feedback, will try using what you recommended and see the results.